# Send Email from Batch File in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

I wanted to send out the email with Below process, is possible if yes, could you please give me some reference,

1. Create an Email Template in SFMC
2. Load CSV file in SFMC sFTP server (All Personalized attributed)
3. Load CSV File in Data Extension
4. Send Email (Template ID will in File)

Can we do this? But Do not want to use the Automation Studio/Journey Builder. In the SFMC I just wanted to Create Template & DE(If required).

Thanks
Sunil

Comment: To not use Automation Studio/Journey Builder would require a completely custom built middleware solution hosted externally from SFMC and connected via the API. Essentially what you would be doing is recreating Automation Studio outside the SFMC ecosystem (a fairly significant development requirement) to handle this task. I doubt that the required investment of money and effort would be worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and it is indeed a very common use case.
You will need to utilise Automation Studio, and configure following activities:

1. [File Drop Automation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_define_a_triggered_automation.htm&type=5)
2. [Import File Activity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_use_an_import_activity.htm&type=5)
3. [Send Email Activity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_send_email_activity.htm&type=5)

Once the file is dropped, the automation starts, and the first step fetches the file and imports it to a sendable Data Extension.

Once successfully imported, the Send Email activity uses that same data extension as a destination for the email.

Make sure the Import File activity uses Overwrite mode, as the email will otherwise be sent to same recipient on multiple automation runs.

Comment: Thanks, @Lunaks, Sorry my question was incomplete, I edited again, Here I Do not want to use Automation Studio/Journey Builder. The use will only create an Email Template in SFMC and DE if required. Might be here I need use Coding/API of SMFC

Comment: So can you help me here

Comment: @SunilNagargoje - To go far into customisations, when an existing solution is right at your feet will for sure require much more background info, and justification from your side. Please provide exactly the context, and why using Automation Studio is not viable solution.